# The deposit was processed with Solana Coin without exchanging honey tokens, so the deposit has not been made yet

Tags: web3.js, pda, cpi

At the phantom

I didn't exchange honey tokens for solana tokens but deposited them into my solana virtual account

It hasn't been deposited into my Solana coin wallet yet

Help me